# Dispatch on concrete-abstract types vs parametric types in Julia

Tags: types, julia

Suppose I have the following abstract and concrete types:

```
abstract type AbstractBox end  

struct SmallBox <: AbstractBox end
struct BigBox <: AbstractBox end
```

and I want to have a general method `ship` that works for any `Box`, but also specific `store` methods that dispatch on the concrete type:

```
function ship(box::AbstractBox) 
    println("ship box")
    # expensive computations
end

function store(box::SmallBox) 
    println("store small box") 
    # expensive computations
end

function store(box::BigBox) 
    println("store big box") 
    # expensive computations
end
```

Say I want to extend `SmallBox` and `BigBox` to have many different fields, with only a few differences between both structures and very similar constructors. I would prefer to reuse the code for the fields and constructors. I know there is the option of using parametric structures like this:

```
struct Box{size} end

function ship(box::Box)
    println("ship box") 
    # expensive computations
end

function store(box::Box{:small}) 
    println("store small box") 
    # expensive computations
end

function store(box::Box{:big}) 
    println("store big box") 
    # expensive computations
end
```

What other options do I have, and what would be the best approach in terms of performance? The `store` method will be called many times, and I want to avoid an `if`-`else` statement in that method for performance.

Comment: "I want to avoid an if-else statement in that method for performance"

You don't need to worry about this. Julia will optimize it for you.